# Why is my Label not disappearing when i call the .place_forget() method?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a an application and it has a function where when "yes" is selected in a ListBox, it runs code that places a label. When I used the .place_forget() method or even the .place() method to move it off screen, I get two versions of the Label or it doesn't move at all and I am very confused as to why.

```
#dropdown event handling
def selected(event):
    entrydisplay = clicked.get()
    if 'Yes' in entrydisplay:
        global extrainfo
        extrainfo = tk.Entry(root, width=32)
        extrainfo.place(x=312,y=201)
        extra_label = tk.Label(root, text='If yes, what team and level of FIRST?', width=28, height=1, bg='red3', fg='black')
        extra_label.place(x=110, y=200)
        interest_label.place(x=130,y=230)
        interest_mechanical.place(x=311, y=228)
        interest_electrical.place(x=311, y=248)
        interest_marketing.place(x=311, y=268)
        interest_design.place(x=311, y=288)
        interest_programming.place(x=311, y=308)
        interest_chairmans.place(x=311, y=328)
        interest_advocacy.place(x=311, y=348)
        interest_leadership.place(x=311, y=368)
        interest_video_production.place(x=311, y=388)
        interest_social_media.place(x=311, y=408)
        other_checkbox.place(x=311, y=428)
        check_box_move = "0"
    if 'No' in entrydisplay:
        check_box_move = "1"

def Clear():
    name.delete(0, END)
    email.delete(0, END)
    clicked.set(options[2])
    grade.delete(0, END)
    interest_mechanical.deselect()
    interest_electrical.deselect()
    interest_marketing.deselect()
    interest_design.deselect()
    interest_programming.deselect()
    interest_chairmans.deselect()
    interest_advocacy.deselect()
    interest_leadership.deselect()
    interest_social_media.deselect()
    interest_video_production.deselect()
    other_checkbox.deselect()
    extrainfo.delete(0, END)
    other_entry.delete(0,END)
    other_entry.place(x=798, y=400)
    extrainfo.place(x=798, y=201)
    extra_label.destroy()
```

Here's a version I wrote so you could replicate my issue:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400+0+0")
root.title("test")


def selected(event):
    global test_label
    test_label = tk.Label(root, text='TEST')
    test_label.place(x=20,y=20)

def Delete():
    test_label.destroy

#DROPDOWN BASE CODE
options = [
    'Yes',
    'No',
    'Select'
]

clicked = StringVar()
clicked.set(options[2])
#ENDS ABOVE
Dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(root, clicked, *options, command=selected)
Dropdown.place(x=311, y=165)

delete_button = tk.Button(root, text='Click to delete text', command=Delete)
delete_button.place(x=100,y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You said, "_move it off screen_" but to where?

Comment: I want to move it off screen so it cannot be seen because the .place_forget method wasn't working and the .destroy method was't working either.

Comment: `place_forget()` will hide the widget temporarily and `destroy()` will completely delete the widget

Comment: To make us understand better, can you actually make an example that does has the same issue that we can copy and run on out system too?

Comment: Yeah, I made it: You should see it above with the other code.

Comment: You update the Q with it

Comment: Ok. It should be updated.

Comment: Inside your `Delete()` it should be `test_label.destroy()` with the `()`

Comment: ‍♂️my bad, let me see if it fixes it

Comment: It fixed it, but it still won't work in my main code. I have `extra_label.destroy()` in my Clear function but it doesn't seem to work even though it works in my test version.

Comment: I am calling it in the "Clear" function above the test code. But i realized in the full code on my computer i hadn't made `extra_label` global like I did in the example and it ended up working. Thank you for your help and guidance!

Comment: Wont you have to say `global extra_label` too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is quite related to global and local scopes. When you define a variable inside of a function it is only defined within that function and for it to be able to be discovered by other functioon you have to make it available to the global scope. Simply say, `global extra_label` for it to be defined in the other functions too.

Hope it cleared your doubt and error.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want that label at all then you can use `destroy()` method to permanently delete the Label from your application. Also you should specify what kind of app you are building to make your question more clear.